# SWIG/CMAKE build problems, trying to install and use new module in GNURadio

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, swig, gnuradio, usrp

I'm trying to make a copy of the USRP Source block included in the UHD module of GNURadio, so that I can freely modify the `work()` function.

For the moment, I'm just trying to make a block that works exactly like the "USRP Source" block. I made a new module called "asat", created the `.cc`, `.h`, `.xml`, `CMakeLists`, and `__init__` files, and got the whole thing to compile and install without an error.

However, when I try and run the GRC .py file, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asat/__init__.py", line 128, in <module> _prepare_asat_swig()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asat/__init__.py", line 32, in _prepare_asat_swig import asat_swig
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asat/asat_swig.py", line 26, in <module> _asat_swig = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asat/asat_swig.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_asat_swig', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asat/_asat_swig.so: undefined symbol: /ZTIN3uhd9key_errorE
```

I've been tearing my hair out trying to resolve the error, and from my googling I suspect it's an issue of libraries not being linked correctly in CMAKE, but I'm new to SWIG/CMAKE and I can't seem to resolve it.

I would really appreciate any help troubleshooting the cause of the error, if I'm on the right track with the libraries, even if someone could suggest a library to link to.

I've made [a github repo with my source and build directories](https://github.com/JoelSpark/gr-asat) for anyone willing to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Joel -

You need to create a SWIG file for your new block so that it will get SWIG'd to Python - otherwise, you won't be able to use it from Python flowgraphs, which is what GRC generates.

There are plenty of *.i SWIG files in the GNURadio source tree that you can look at. Alternatively, I recommend you ask on the gnuradio-discuss mailing list, which is where nearly all GNURadio support takes place (I'm the only one I know of that monitors SO):

https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio

Cheers,

Ben